# Iterating through a std::vector<char>

Tags: c++11, iterator, char, stdvector

I have some legacy C which iterates through `buffer_1` allocated with some valid memory. `buffer_2` is made to point to parts of `buffer_1` and the iteration keeps moving random 20 places ahead. Following is the code:

```
char* buffer_1;
char* buffer_2;
size_t buffer_length;

buffer_length = 2000; // somerandom value

if (buffer_length > 0) {
    buffer_1 = malloc(buffer_length);
    for(buffer_2 = buffer_1; buffer_2 < buffer_1 + buffer_length; buffer_2 += 20) {
        // Some random logic
    }
}
```

I want to make the above code C++ 11 compliant by declaring `buffer_1` and `buffer_2` as `std::vector<char>`s like below.

```
std::vector<char> buffer_1;
std::vector<char> buffer_2;
```

Then I think I would need to use an iterator over `buffer_1` do something like below?

```
if (buffer_length > 0) {
    buffer_1.reserve(buffer_length);
    for(std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer_1.begin(); it != buffer_1.end(); it += 20) {
        buffer_2.data() = *it;
    }
}
```

is the above way of iterating through a `std::vector<char>` correct? Does it do exactly what the following for statement does?

```
for(buffer_2 = buffer_1; buffer_2 < buffer_1 + buffer_length; buffer_2 += 20)
```

Comment: Sigh... `for(auto it = begin(begin(buffer_1)); it < end(buffer_1); it += 20) {`.

Comment: Its `begin(buffer_1)´ and not `begin(begin(buffer_1))`. But I get the point. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make the above code C++ 11 compliant

That code is already valid C++11.

> is the above way of iterating through a std::vector correct? Does it do exactly what the following for statement does?

No and no:

- You need to use `resize` rather than `reserve`.
- If the buffer's size is not a multiple of 20 it will not work.
- And this `buffer_2.data() = *it;` does not make sense because `data()` is simply a pointer to the internal buffer.

Comment: By saying "I want make the code C++11 compliant", I meant to C++11 implement exactly what the C code is doing.

Comment: Buffer size is multiple of 20. I can guarantee that part surely since it works with the C code.